# DateDiff between years resulting wrong result

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, datediff

I got this function from the internet. It's doing well when counting days so far, but when the dates is from different year, the result is wrong.
Example:

```
dateFrom = "2017-12-26"
dateTo = "2018-01-02"
```

the result will be 28 days, when it supposed to be 6 days.

Here is the function:

```
Public Function NetWorkdays(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, arrHolidays)
    Dim lngDays
    Dim lngSaturdays
    Dim lngSundays
    Dim lngHolidays
    Dim lngAdjustment
    Dim dtTest
    Dim i, x

    lngDays = DateDiff("d", dtStartDate, dtEndDate)
    lngSundays = DateDiff("ww", dtStartDate, dtEndDate, vbSunday)
    lngSaturdays = DateDiff("w", IIf(Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday) = vbSaturday, dtStartDate, dtStartDate - Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday)), dtEndDate)

    For x = LBound(arrHolidays) To UBound(arrHolidays)
        For i = 0 To lngDays
            dtTest = DateAdd("d", i, dtStartDate)
            If arrHolidays(x) = dtTest And Weekday(dtTest) <> 1 And Weekday(dtTest) <> 7 Then
                lngHolidays = lngHolidays + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday) = vbSunday Or Weekday(dtStartDate, vbSunday) = vbSaturday Then
        lngAdjustment = 0
    Else
        lngAdjustment = 1
    End If

    NetWorkdays = lngDays - lngSundays - lngSaturdays - lngHolidays + lngAdjustment
End Function

Public Function IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)
    If expr Then IIf = truepart Else IIf = falsepart
End function
```

Can anybody point it out anything to repair?

Comment: I wouldn’t use it if you don’t understand what it is doing. Before I reuse any code from the internet I analyse what it does and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateFrom = #2017-12-26#
dateTo = #2018-01-02#
Msgbox Dateto - datefrom,, "Result"
```

returns

```
---------------------------
Result
---------------------------
7
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Please explain why you answer works and what the OP did wrong code only answers are not suitable for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

As indiated by the type prefixes in the prototype:

```
Public Function NetWorkdays(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, arrHolidays)
```

the function expects Dates, not Strings. Evidence:

```
Option Explicit

(copy of function)

Dim dp, n
For Each dp In Array(Array("2017-12-26", "2018-01-02"))
   On Error Resume Next
    n = NetWorkdays(dp(0), dp(1), Array())
    If Err Then n = Err.Description
   On Error GoTo 0
    WScript.Echo TypeName(dp(0)), dp(0), dp(1), n 
    dp(0) = CDate(dp(0))
    dp(1) = CDate(dp(1))
    WScript.Echo TypeName(dp(0)), dp(0), dp(1), NetWorkdays(dp(0), dp(1), Array()) 

Next
```

output (german locale):

```
cscript 47921079.vbs
String 2017-12-26 2018-01-02 Typenkonflikt
Date 26.12.2017 02.01.2018 6
```

Depending on versions, locales and the phase of the moon, you may have to replace the CDate() call with something more reliable.